# Parser for CallGraph in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, tokenize

I am able to convert a C code into bitcode and then to CallGraph using LLVM. Now I need to perform parsing for various metrics purposes. How to proceed?

Call Graph looks like this:

```
Call graph node <<null function>><<0x949dc90>>  #uses=0
  CS<0x0> calls function 'main'
  CS<0x0> calls function 'printf'

Call graph node for function: 'printf'<<0x949d220>>  #uses=2
  CS<0x0> calls external node

Call graph node for function: 'main'<<0x94ac7f8>>  #uses=1
  CS<0x949e3a0> calls function 'printf'
```

Comment: Do you have any previous experience with parsing? What have you tried so far? BTW just curious, what is bitcode?

Comment: http://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html

Comment: I am just concerned with the CallGraph output that I have displayed in my post. BitCode is just the intermediate step I need to generate to get that call graph. I have some experience in Python, XML parsing. None in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any previous experience in Java this may be a tall order.

You will first need to establish the format of the call graph. Then tokenize either using word boundaries, regular expression or a parser generator such as antlr.

Beyond that, the problem is too large for a complete answer on StackOverflow. Try to study these options and ask specific questions the option you choose when you encounter problems.

Comment: I will start with Antlr and see what I can do with that. Thanks

Comment: Can you recommend any beginner tutorial for Antlr. I am only able to find complex tutorials.